# How can I translate Python onnxruntime code to Rust tract_onnx?

Tags: machine-learning, rust, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm trying to translate a Python script using onnxruntime to Rust using tract_onnx. The specific POC I'm trying to implement is [the `rothe_vgg.py` script](https://github.com/onnx/models/blob/master/vision/body_analysis/age_gender/rothe_vgg.py) from the ONNX Model Zoo. This script uses three models:

- ultraface face detection ([`version-RFB-320.onnx`](https://github.com/onnx/models/blob/master/vision/body_analysis/ultraface/models/version-RFB-320.onnx))
- `vgg_ilsvrc_16_age_imdb_wiki.onnx` and `vgg_ilsvrc_16_gender_imdb_wiki.onnx` [age and gender models](https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/vision/body_analysis/age_gender#models)

For now, I'm trying just the first model to detect faces. I can get [the example Python code](https://github.com/onnx/models/blob/41ccf18ba5a815dab714899ac234e9b1e4293c20/vision/body_analysis/age_gender/rothe_vgg.py#L33) to work:

```py
face_detector_onnx = "models/version-RFB-320.onnx"
face_detector = ort.InferenceSession(face_detector_onnx)

def faceDetector(orig_image, threshold = 0.7):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(orig_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (320, 240))
    image_mean = np.array([127, 127, 127])
    image = (image - image_mean) / 128
    image = np.transpose(image, [2, 0, 1])
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = image.astype(np.float32)

    input_name = face_detector.get_inputs()[0].name
    confidences, boxes = face_detector.run(None, {input_name: image})
    boxes, labels, probs = predict(orig_image.shape[1], orig_image.shape[0], confidences, boxes, threshold)
    return boxes, labels, probs
```

I'm basing my tract_onnx translation on the [onnx-mobilenet-v2 example](https://github.com/sonos/tract/blob/68db0209c9ffd1b91dff82884f4ae03b3622dd34/examples/onnx-mobilenet-v2/src/main.rs). My version currently looks like this:

```rust
let model = onnx()
        .model_for_path("version-RFB-320.onnx")?
        .with_input_fact(
            0,
            InferenceFact::dt_shape(f32::datum_type(), tvec!(1, 3, 240, 320)),
        )?
        .into_optimized()?
        .into_runnable()?;

let image = image::open("bruce.jpg").unwrap().to_rgb8();
let resized = image::imageops::resize(&image, 240, 320, ::image::imageops::FilterType::Triangle);

let image: Tensor = tract_ndarray::Array4::from_shape_fn((1, 3, 240, 320), |(_, c, y, x)| {
    resized[(x as _, y as _)][c] as f32 / 255.0
}).into();

let result = model.run(tvec!(image))?;
```

I'm running into an issue with the translation of the resized image into a tensor:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Image index (240, 0) out of bounds (240, 320)'.
```

Is this an issue of not having the right dimensions or the right ordering of each dimension? Am I missing something?

I know I haven't yet implemented the other translations, which are my next questions: how can I properly normalize with `image_mean`, transpose, and expand dimensionality?

Comment: Are you sure that the order of the dimensions is the same when manipulating images and arrays? Eg. are you sure that images are not `width, height` and arrays `rows, columns`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the project https://github.com/recoai/visual-search. It implements several deep learning models in Rust using ONNX. You can configure any deep learning model image transformations or use 4 preconfigured models.

Here is an example how to configure the model. The project doesn't support segmentation models but the image transformation pipeline is working.

```rust
let model_config = ModelConfig {
    model_name: "SqueezeNet".into(),
    model_url: "https://github.com/onnx/models/raw/master/vision/classification/squeezenet/model/squeezenet1.1-7.onnx".into(),
    image_transformation: TransformationPipeline {
        steps: vec![
            ResizeRGBImageAspectRatio { image_size: ImageSize { width: 224, height: 224 }, scale: 87.5, filter: FilterType::Nearest }.into(),
            CenterCrop { crop_size: ImageSize {width: 224, height: 224} }.into(),
            ToArray {}.into(),
            Normalization { sub: [0.485, 0.456, 0.406], div: [0.229, 0.224, 0.225], zeroone: true }.into(),
            ToTensor {}.into(),
        ]
    },
    image_size: ImageSize { width: 224, height: 224 },
    layer_name: Some("squeezenet0_pool3_fwd".to_string()),
    channels: Channels::CWH
}
```